# Can't update args in react-query(mutation) inside formik

Tags: formik, react-query

When i call my mutation function inside formik, args do not assign. it's always empty. I wonder why it happens, also i try to use `useState` hook to pass args from formik to `useMutation` hook but nothing works. What i missing?

useMutation:

```
const changePasswordOnClick = useMutation<Record<string, string>, undefined, ChangePassword>(
        () => axios.post(
            url,
        {email: '', password:'', new_password: ''},
        ),
        {
            onSuccess: (req) => {

                console.log('Success!!!!', req)

            },

            onError: (req) => {
                console.log('onError', req);
            },
        },
    );
```

formik:

```
<Formik initialValues={{password: '', email: '', new_password:'' }}
              validationSchema={validateSchema}

       onSubmit={async (data,{setSubmitting, resetForm})=>{
                                    
       setSubmitting(true)
                                     
       changePasswordOnClick.mutate({
                      email:data.email, // always empty, why?                               
                      password: data.password, //always empty, why?                                       
                      new_password: data.new_password //always empty, why?
                       })
                      console.log('Submit', data) // has data
                      setSubmitting(false)
                                                           
                     closeModalWindow.current.click()
                     resetForm()
                                }}>
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Need to divide axios and react-query

First(axios func which accept args)

```
const setNewPassword = (email, password, new_password) => axios.post(url,
```

Second(useMutation hook)

```
 const changePasswordOnClick = useMutation(setNewPassword, {
        onSuccess:(data)=>{
            console.log(data);
        }

    })
```

Formik (form)

```
  <Formik initialValues={{password:'', email: '', new_password:'' }}
      validationSchema={validateSchema}
      onSubmit={(values,{setSubmitting, resetForm})=>{
              setSubmitting(true)
               changePasswordOnClick.mutate({
                             email:values.email, 
                             password: values.password
                             new_password:values.new_password})
                              
                              setSubmitting(false)
                              resetForm()
                  }}
```